# add pages to sidemenu of side menu project template

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I created a project using the sidemenu template.

```
ionic start projectName sidemenu --v2
```

after that i generated another page using: `ionic g page pageName`

what I want to do is to add this generated page to the side menu.

can you please help me, I'm newbie to ionic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: add the generated page by importing it in homepage.declare the homepage as rootpage in generated page(pageName)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add your new page to the `pages array` as shown below.

**Git repo:** [**Sample Side menu**](https://github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/Ionic2SideMenu)

*app.component.ts*

```
import { PageNamePage } from "../pages/page-name/page-name";

    export class MyApp {

        this.pages = [
          { title: 'Page One', component: Page1 },
          { title: 'Page Two', component: Page2 },
          { title: 'Page Three', component: PageNamePage }//your new page
        ];
    }
```

You have to add new page as shown below inside the `app.module.ts`.I have removed default code for clarity.

*app.module.ts* :

```
import { PageNamePage } from "../pages/page-name/page-name";//your new page

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PageNamePage,//new page
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    PageNamePage,//new page
  ],
 })
export class AppModule { }
```

*Side Menu Now :*

[image]

Comment: please also mention that the user would also need to add the page in the `app.module.ts` file, both in the `declarations` and the `entryComponents` arrays :)